# How to calculate polar derivatives with python?

Tags: python, math, numpy, polar-coordinates

I have 2-dimensional arrays of cartesian data z = f(x,y). If I want a numerical derivative in x direction I do (with Python's numpy array)

```
lag = 10
dx = (data[lag:,:] - data[:-lag,:])/float(lag)
```

Now, with the same data I have a center point and I want the derivative to be towards to this point i.e. radial derivative dr. And also I want the corresponding perpendicular component i.e. tangential derivative dt.

Is there a function/library/block of code that does this? Like

`dr, dt = nablaPolar(data, centerpoint)?`

Note that the mathematics have to be correct (the lag parameter depends on the distance to origin).

Answer (score 2):

The radial (r) and tangential (t) derivatives are the components of the gradient in polar coordinates:

∇f = (df/dr, 1/r df/dt)

As your data is stored in a cartesian array, you'll need to express this as cartesian derivatives:

dr = df/dr

= (df/dx)*(dx/dr) + (df/dy)/(dy/dr)

= (df/dx)/(2x) + (df/dy)/(2y)

and,

dt = (1/r)*(df/dt)

= [(df/dx)*(dx/dt) + (df/dy)*(dy/dt)]/(x^2 + y^2)

= [(df/dx)*(x^2 + y^2)/(-y) + (df/dx)*(x^2 + y^2)/(x)]/(x^2 + y^2)

= (df/dy)/x - (df/dx)/y

To compute this in python,

```
def nablaPolar(data, centerpoint, lag=10):
    x, y = centerpoint
    dfx = (data[x+lag][y] - data[x-lag][y])/float(lag)
    dfy = (data[x][y+lag] - data[x][y-lag])/float(lag)
    dr = dfx/(2*x) + dfy/(2*y)
    dt = dfy/x - dfx/y
    return dr, dt
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think you have to modify this a bit... The centerpoint is related to indices of the data. the r is dependent on x- x0 and y - y0, where x and y are the array indices and x0 and y0 are the coordinates of the centerpoint. Something like r^2 = (x-x0)^2 + (y-y0)^2. This adds some constants, right? The above works if the center is at (0,0).